# How to search AU for a string containing “$”?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, search

Today I tried to search for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048301/507051), but the only thing I could remember from it was `$_`, so I tried to search for this term:
https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%24_

To my surprise the result page claimed to search for a single underscore only and didn’t find a single post:

> results found containing _

I read [the help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching) and tried to quote the string without any avail, so I got curious:

- searching for `$_` → `results found containing _`
  0 results
- searching for `$@` (without single quotes!) → `results found containing "$@"`
  0 results
- searching for `$*` → `results found containing *`
  678,109 results, not necessarily containing either `$` or `*`
- searching for `$1` → `results found containing 1`
  91,291 results, exactly like searching for `1`

As neither of those searches give the expected result:

How do I properly search for a string containing `$` using the site’s search function?

<sup>Please do not comment or answer with “Did you try [third-party search engine]?” – I am well aware of google and the like, but if we have a search function it should work properly on its own.</sup>

I found [meta.SE: Search terms with dollar signs ($) are ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39874/371617), but this solution doesn’t work:

- https://askubuntu.com/search?q="%24_" →  `results found containing "$_"`: 0 results
- https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%24_ →  `results found containing _`: 0 results

The odd thing is: It works well if one [searches for the string formatted as code](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=code%3A"%24_")! But we all know, not everybody formats a simply thing like `$@` as code every times, plus it may appear in a quotation – there has to be a way to search for it!

Comment: Huh. So do we have lousy escaping happening here, or an injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote trick used to work - it was even documented in the help center!

Somewhere along the line, we dropped support for symbol-searches. Yes, that's annoying, but that's how it is. Until such a time as we're able to devote time and resources to improving search, you'll have to rely on 3rd-party search engines for tasks like these.

If this is ever supported again, we'll update [the help center page](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching) to reflect that.